# Regex find "N/A" word

Tags: regex

I've been trying to find a regex expression that find `N/A` in a string.

A sample string would be:

```
/* Location : 06 Roy Chimaltenango  for device : Roy Chimaltenango 6-1 has 1N/A's with 20 traffic. */
```

and the closest I've come is with the regex:

```
/(\b\/A\b)/
```

which selects `/A`

but if I enter

```
/(\bN\/A\b)/
```

it wont match anything

Any help on why?

Comment: It depends on the language you're using, but have you tried it without the `\b`s? Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `N/A` substring is preceeded by a `1`, i.e. `1N/A's`. Your regex `/(\bN\/A\b)/` has a `\b` word boundary at the start, but there is no word boundary between `1` and `N` because they are both considered word characters.

Try this:

```
(N\/A\b)
```

You could probably remove the last `\b` as well, but perhaps you have other strings where it is important:

```
(N\/A)
```